How to find the focus and the directrix of the general second degree equation?
I know the formula will be extremely lengthy and unworthy of remembering except for the Parabola. Is there a method to find the focus and directrix for a general second degree equation efficiently(even an algorithm-esque answer will be appreciated) Thank you.

A first answer here

If it is a conic with a center (ellipse or hyperbola) with intrinsic equation $f(x,y)=0$, you have to find firstly the center (obtained by solving the system  $\partial f/\partial x =0,\partial f/\partial y =0$ then, having a homogeneous equation (with new coordinates $X,Y$) : $AX^2+2BXY+CY^2=1$, then compute $\theta$ such that $\tan 2 \theta = \frac{2B}{A-C}$ which will give you the rotation to apply to the conic to obtain a classical simple equation. After that, all is easy.
